# pandas comparing series with numpy float gives TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In `pandas`, you can do this:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6]], columns=list('abcd'))
>>> x
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  3  4  5  6
>>> 2 < x.a
0    False
1     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

However, when I try it with it with a `numpy` float:

```
>>> np.float64(2) < x.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/simon/Documents/workspace/rent-my-rez/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 741, in wrapper
    if len(self) != len(other):
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Is there some way around this (which doesn't involve casting the `numpy` float to a regular float), or some way I can monkey patch the `Series` class from pandas to implement reverse comparison? I've looked around in the source code for where comparison is implemented, but I couldn't find it, so a reference to the location in the code would be very helpful

(I am aware that it is easily fixed by changing the order of comparison, but I am asking this more out of interest, as I would like to understand the source code more)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me ...

Comment: works fine for me in Python 3, I suppose you use Python 2? You can try `x.a.values` which should return an np.array.

Comment: You are going down a rabbit hole! The order of assignment and comparison, I believe comes from C. Do your digging in C.

Comment: Python 2 here and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue talked about [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13006) and fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/13307), making it tough to find the source if you (like me) are running `0.18.0` and trying to find the equivalent lines on github. If you look on github at `0.18.0` instead of `master` you can see the relevant lines, e.g. line 739 [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.18.0/pandas/core/ops.py)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should update your pandas version to the newest, for there is an update for your bugs. I just update it 0.19.2 by pip in Python 2.7.3. Now the bug is fixed.